# aws efs connection timeout at mount

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/getting-started.html) tutorial to mount efs on AWS EC2 instance but when Iam executing the mount command

```
sudo mount -t nfs4 -o vers=4.1 $(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone).[EFS-ID].efs.[region].amazonaws.com:/ efs
```

I am getting connection time out every time.

```
mount.nfs4: Connection timed out
```

What may be the problem here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you make sure you have attached the security group in this step https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/gs-step-one-create-ec2-resources.html

Comment: @error2007s thanks for pointing that out, it seems like I didn't added the default security group due to which I was getting connection timeout.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct. thank You

Comment: Are you able to load the site: http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone from your browser (outside of your EC2 instance. just from your regular computer?) I cannot ans suspect AWS server is down?

Comment: @user1709076 this error was due to non communication between efs and ec2. Resolution was to add the efs and ec2 in same security group with all traffic allowed or open port 2049 in the security group.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

I found the accepted answer here to be incorrect & insecure, and Bao's answer above is very close - except you don't need NFS Inbound on your EC2 (mount target) security group. You just need a security group assigned to your EC2 (even with no rules) so that your EFS Security group can be limited to that security group... you know, for security! Here's what I found works:

- Create a new security group for your EC2 instance. Name it `EFS Target`, and leave all the rules blank
- Create a new security group for your EFS Mount. Name it `EFS Mount`, and in this one add the `inbound` rule for NFS. Set the SOURCE for this rule to the `EFS Target` security group you created above. This limits EFS to only being able to connect to EC2 instances that have the `EFS Mount` security group assigned (See below). If you're not worried about that, you can select "Any" from the Source dropdown and it'll work just the same, without the added level of security
- Go to the EC2 console, and add the `EFS Target` group to your EC2 instance, assuming you're adding the extra security
- Go to the EFS Console, select your EFS and choose Manage File System Access

  - For each EFS Mount Target (availability zone), you need to add the `EFS Mount` security group and remove the VPC Default group (if you haven't already)
- The mount command in the AWS documentation should work now

I don't like how they mixed vernacular here in terms of EC2 being a mount-target, but also EFS has individual mount-targets for each availability zone. Makes their documentation very confusing, but following the steps above allowed me to mount an EFS securely on an Ubuntu server.

Comment: Great work Scott. This should be the accepted answer. Nice way to bend the security groups to your will.

Comment: @Scott thank you, the best answer. I suggest to add TL;DR: SecGroups in EFS configuration are those EFS belongs to, not NFS clients as one may think.

Comment: Thank you Scott, this solved my issue and i agree that this is the best answer, and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I mostly followed Scott's advice.  What I would add is that my EFS was added to my default VPC security group, and the EFS said it would accept traffic from anyone a member of the default security group.  So all I had to do was add that default security group to the EC2 trying to mount.  Now that is not entirely secure and is not the recommended path for all people, but just getting something working this might be the fastest route.

Answer (score 31):

Add type with NFS and port 2049 to the Inbound of your security group that your EC2 instances and EFS running on. It works for me.

Bao

Comment: This is the correct answer. To your EC2 instance security group add Type NFS (it's already configured to port 2049) with a source of the security group the EFS is in and it starts working. Making port 22 public as suggested in the above answer is unnecessary and in a lot of cases not a good idea, and does not solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, this definitely worked. But I got access denied when connecting from EC2. Fix: Delete EFS file system, and now create an EFS, but this time during the setup itself, you have to assign the security group to each mount target from that stage it self. 

Somehow, changing security groups of mount targets after creating the EFS was not working for me.

https://superuser.com/questions/1100770/unable-to-mount-elastic-file-system-on-ec2-mount-nfs4-connection-timed-out

Answer (score 4):

A different answer here, as I faced a very similar error and none of the answers fit.

I was trying to mount a NFS like below (in my case EKS was doing that on my behalf, but I tested the very same command manually in the worker node with the same result):

```sh
[root@host ~]# mount -t nfs fs-abc1234.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:/persistentvolumes /mnt/test
```

Output was: `mount.nfs: Connection timed out`

When I simply tried the same command, but using `/` as the path:

```sh
[root@host ~]# mount -t nfs fs-abc1234.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:/ /mnt/test
```

It worked like a charm!

I really do not understand how a possible wrong or missing path can lead to a `time out` kind of error, but that was the only thing that could fix the problem for me, all the network configuration remained the same.

As I was using EKS/Kubernetes, I dedcided to mount `/`, which works, and then use [subPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath) to change the volume mounting point in the container configuration.

Comment: This was my exact problem. It seems we cannot mount an EFS missing path. The `volumeMounts.subPath` works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps

1. Create a security group allowing NFS traffic inbound.
2. The EC2 which will be used for mounting - note down the respective region.
3. Go to EFS - select FileSystem - Network - Edit the security group corresponding to the EC2 region (Step 2) - add security group from Step 1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and following the Amazon AWS guides it worked for one server of mine but another one didn't want to mount the EFS volume. Analyzing the local server messages log I've found that the outgoing TCP traffic was BLOCKED even if the associated Security Group was set to allow any outgoing traffic (on any port, any external address etc.). Setting a rule on the Security Group to allow TCP connections from EC2 host to EFS service on port 2049 didn't get any effect while instead setting a specific rule on the local iptable firewall got the job and resolved the issue. I can't figure out why there was this discrepancy but it worked for me. As far as I know the local iptables fw should not be touched and it should obtain the rules directly from the SG from AWS console.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. After a while I noticed it picks 3 randoms subnets for the mount-points, one per AZ.

I was unlucky one of these subnets didn't had the correct NACL.
After assigning the correct subnet/SG per mount point it worked immediately fine using DNS and IP.

Answer (score 0):

I got the Answer.
This is happening when the subnet is blocking the flow.
Go to subnets (which you have selected while creating the EFS) and allow the traffic to particular target systems.

1. checkthe  EFS file systems subnet.
2. go to subnet
3. add a rule
4. allow all-traffic ( you can  give specific to your target systems)

This worked in my case

Answer (score 0):

Allow security group of ec2 into mount target security group of EFS.

Answer (score -1):

For me it was simply that the an **EC2 disk was full**.

I've cleaned it, reboot the instance and it worked.

To check your disk use: `df -h` or `du -h --max-depth=1 /`